# Examples of unsupervised neural networks that are not self-supervised

Tags: neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, self-supervised-learning

I'm trying to understand if such things exist.  For the NN to learn it seems that we need a measure of error and thus we need labels.  In the case of auto-encodoers, which are considered unsupervised, the labels are just the input so the NN is self-supervised.  In the case of GAN's we know everything the generator creates is fake and all of our initial sample is true and thus it seems to be self-supervised as well.  Is there another case?  Is there an unsupersived, not self-supervised NN example?

Comment: Does a "masked" model like word2vec count? It's not exactly self-supervised in the same fashion as an autoencoder.

Comment: From what I understand word2vec is unsupervised dimension reduction using PCA or TSNE.  I was thinking of a neural network.

Comment: Word2vec was originally a NN. It's common to use PCA or tSNE on the resulting vectors for data visualization. I can post an answer.

Comment: Very interesting.  So how does it work?  If I use a NN to run a regression, would that be supervised or unsupervised?  The data gives us the correct labels to begin with.  We have labels but we don't make them.

Answer (score 7):

Unlabeled-unlabeled learning (UU learning, by analogy to Positive-unlabeled learning, a.k.a. PU learning) is unsupervised in the sense that the data are not annotated with labels, but you know (or have an estimate of) the probabilities of each class for each set of unlabeled data. It can be applied to the case where the model learns from two sets of **unlabeled** data, where one set of unlabeled data has class probabilities $\pi_1$ and a second with class probabilities $\pi_2 \neq \pi_1$.

This is discussed in Chapter 8 of *Machine Learning from Weak Supervision: An Empirical Risk Minimization Approach* (2023) by Masashi Sugiyama, Han Bao, Takashi Ishida, Nan Lu, Tomoya Sakai.

The book discusses a number of alternative weakly-supervised learning scenarios, but this is probably the scenario with the *least* supervision.